# How do I update the source file name in Talend

Tags: talend

I have the **source file** on HDFS and I want to write the output file with a new column to have the name of the source file for each row. I have my Talend job like:

tHDFSGet --> tInputFilePositional --> tmap --> tfileoutputfile

Please help get the file name for each row in the new column.

Comment: how are you getting filename for tInputFilePositional - if its from a global variable, you can add a new column in tMap and use this global variable to get the file name

Comment: No, Its not a global variable....
Should I pass it through tjava and assign the filename to a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `thdfsList` to get the filename in it and used

```
StringHandling.RIGHT(StringHandling.LEFT(((String)globalMap.get("tHDFSList_2_CURRENT_FILEPATH")),StringHandling.LEN(((String)globalMap.get("tHDFSList_2_CURRENT_FILEPATH")))+6),7)
```

This trimmed the filepath to just the filename.